# Showing contour line elevation labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour

I have a contour map in DXF imported to QGIS. How do I turn on the elevation labels for each contour so they are visible. I thought I had done it by clicking on the layer and selecting properties > labels - single label > Label with - layer. All I get is a '0' for each contour.

Is there info in the DXF missing?

Answer (score 7):

Right click the layer and open the attribute table - the elevations should be in here under one of the columns. Identify the name of the relevant elevations column, and select this from the drop down menu when choosing 'label with'.

If the elevations aren't included in the attributes, then the data you require is missing. Feel free to send screenshots of any steps (perhaps the attribute table?) for further clarity.